# black screen before login screen

Tags: boot, login-screen

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my laptop. I installed the drivers for my graphics card from [AMD Support](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Ubuntu%20x86%2064) (first download). Then I restarted my laptop. Now I have a black screen before the graphical login screen with the user selection.  GRUB works fine; I can see its advanced options.  This screen happens after the disc has been decrypted.

What's happening?  How can I fix it?

Comment: The latest version of LTS or are you using 15? Also is it just a blank black screen or is it the gub black screen >  can you login un to grub in black screen Ctl Alt F1? Please update your answer thx

Comment: I use 14.04 LTS. I see grub also I can use advence options. So my grub works fine. Problem appears after decryption disk. I see empty black sreen instead of login site with selection users.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds alot like a problem I had recently, as detailed at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241577/grub-menu-not-visible .

The short version is:

1. `sudoedit /etc/default/grub`, find the line that says `#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480` and uncomment it (delete the `#`), and save your changes.
2. `sudo update-grub` (This step is important. I missed it the first couple times and accomplished absolutely nothing.)
3. Reboot.

If that works, you will see the grub menu on your next startup. Assuming it does work, follow the linked instructions to determine the screen resolutions your system supports and step up through them until things stop working, then back up one step.

Hope that helps.

Comment: My grub works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the problem, guessing should be compatibility issue. You can check the log in the following paths like `/var/log/syslog`,`var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log`.

It seems hard to correct the problem by changing the set of NVIDIA's drive or GUI modules considering that i have tried my such programs by googling.

My solution is: **Change your Monitor cable. Don't use HDMI cable but DVI cable**. If you had tried this solution but failed, you should maybe read the logs mentioned above and try to understand and fix it manually.